# Origin of the quote "mad impetuous boy"

Tags: dialogue

I occasionally run across a phrase containing the words 'mad impetuous boy' in a number of movies.  Probably most famous is a Pete Lorre lookalike in a Loony Tunes cartoon being slapped by Daffy Duck.

It's such a specific phrase, I wonder if there's an origin, and due to the nature of Loony Tunes cartoons being full of references to the culture of the time, I suspect the origin is not the Loony Tunes cartoon.

I googled it for some time without getting anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Tried tracking the dialogue but could not find any origin story in english literature. Curiously enough this dialog was first used in the movie "**Born Free**", released in the year 1966.

> You mad, impetuous boy.

http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M4847a56b/Born+Free/You+mad%2C+impetuous+boy.

Comment: *"this dialog was first used"* Er, no it wasn't. It appeared in the 1947 cartoon [Birth of a Notion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0039189/quotes) (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_th7GO7dUJI#t=00m47s)), like the OP said. OP simply confused Daffy Duck for Donald Duck.

Answer (score 2):

An earlier example of the phrase is found in various episodes of the Alan Young radio show. An example is in this show